# iOS parse query on PFFile and PFObjects not fetching in order

Tags: ios, parsing

I'm not really sure if it's my code, or if it's parse not fetching the query correctly. I have a "Photo" class table filled with PFFiles that are photos, and each photo has a corresponding caption of string type. When I query the table/class, the captions fetch in correct descending order, but rarely do the photos. As a result the photos don't have the correct corresponding captions (strings). I used the getDataInBackgroundWithBlock method for the PFFile because I was getting the notorious "there is a long running parse operation" warning with out it. HELP! Here is my code:

```
- (void)queryParse
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {

                [objectIDArray addObject:object.objectId];
                NSString *postedBy = object[@"postedBy"];
                [postedByFeedArray addObject:postedBy];
                NSString *caption = object[@"caption"];
                [captionFeedArray addObject:caption];

                PFFile *file = object[@"photoFile"];
                [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {
                         [photoFeedArray addObject:data];
                     }
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                        [_tableView reloadData];
                    });
                }];

            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: This may be stupid but why not just use a `PFQueryTableViewController` and a `PFImageView` so a lot of this code is automatically managed and pagination is already at your hands?

Comment: I found out about those options after I wrote this code and after the project was well on its way to being completed. I also believed that Parse would be stable enough to function correctly with out using ALL of their products. I guess I don't have an option

Comment: I didn't really look at your code so you very well could just have an error in your code.  Their code is stable enough, its just there is a lot of extra code that you would need to had to ensure stability.  Its how it is if you wrote your own backend and your own code to interface to it.  Parse isn't stopping you from grabbing your information your own way but they just want to make it easier and more efficient by adding all the extra code into their own classes to save you time.  Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm going to try the PFTable and ImageView. I'm not confident in the results, but why not. Their forum boards aren't very helpful that's for sure.

Comment: Yeah... I'm not a huge fan.  Their documentation, tutorials, and guides are pretty nice.  
Here's the guide: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#top/iOS
Here's the documentation: https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/
Here's the video tutorial for PFQueryTableView: https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-table (A little dated but very nice)  Hope this helps!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Unwrap PFFiles.

```
    func loadData() {
    var findUser = PFUser.query()
    findUser.whereKey("username", equalTo: profileUser.username)
    findUser.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock { (object:PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error == nil) {
            if let profileImage:PFFile = object["profileImage"] as? PFFile {
                profileImage.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData:NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {
                        let image:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                        self.profileImageView.image = image
                    }
                    else{
                        println(error)
                        self.presentErrorMessage(error)
                    }
                })
            }

        }
        else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println(error)
            self.presentErrorMessage(error)
        }
    }
}
```